# Return the url to its original state after refresh

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I wrote this form using html and PHP  on my webpage. This form receives a number as input. and adds the desired number to 2. And prints the output.

For example, if we put the number 5 at the input and press the submit button , The page refreshes to this URL : mysite.com/page1/?sen=5&sub=Submit

And the number 7 is printed on the output.

So far so good. But when we refresh the page in this case , The submitted information will not be deleted and the url will remain "mysite.com/page1/?sen=5&sub=Submit" .And the output is not cleared and still remains 7.

In this case, I want the page to return to its original state, (mysite.com/page1) . And the output is cleared.

what's the solution?

```
<form name="form1" action="" method="GET">
<input type="number" name="sen" placeholder="سن">
<input type="submit" name="sub" placeholder="ثبت">
</form>
<?php if ( isset($_GET['sub'])){
    //$sen1=0;
     $sen1 = $_GET['sen'];
    if (empty($sen1)){
         echo "ooopppss";
    }

else {
echo $sen1 + 2; }
}
?>
```

Comment: The reload feature a browser allow you to refresh the actual url. So if the url is `mysite.com/page1/?sen=5&sub=Submit` clicking on reload will reload this url. You can't change this behaviour. Best option would be to create a button that redirect to `mysite.com/page1/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can easily be achieved with Javascript. Here's a very basic example.

You could make this a function. Then call it once to invoke it on a page refresh, and if you want to invoke it on button actions, you can use an html [onclick](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) attribute, or an event listener.

```
<script>
function clearFormAndParams() {
    // Target each form input and set the value to "".
    document.querySelector("input[name='sen']").value = "";

    // Split the url by the "?" and then set the value to the first half.
    window.location = window.location.href.split("?")[0];
}

clearFormAndParams(); // runs on refresh

var submitButton = document.querySelector("input[name='sub']");
submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    clearFormAndParams();
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve your goal by modifying your code to store the results of calculation in a cookie / session variable and redirecting to the same page without the extra parameters like so:

```
<form name="form1" action="" method="GET">
<input type="number" name="sen" placeholder="سن">
<input type="submit" name="sub" placeholder="ثبت">
</form>
<?php 

if ( isset($_GET['sub'])){
    $sen1 = $_GET['sen'];
    if (empty($sen1)){
         echo "ooopppss";
    }
    setcookie("result", $sen1 + 2);
    header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}

echo $_COOKIE['result']; 

?>
```